# How do I send data over TCP from a SIM5320A?

Tags: at-commands, 3g

**NOTE**: I have been using [this](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/tcpip_application_note_for_wcdma_solution_v2.0_0.pdf) as a reference.

After recently purchasing a SIM5320A breakout board ([the board](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-3g-cellular-gps-breakout/downloads)) I have been trying to connect it to a TCP server. After having to connect the board to an Arduino and turn the Arduino into a middle man (Data Mode, wouldn't receive +++ over the USB connection). I have tried using Data Mode (I can receive data, but I can't send anything) and Command Mode (whenever I try to use *AT+CIPOPEN=0,"TCP",[IP address in quotes],[port]* I get *+IP ERROR: Operation not supported*).

All I need to be able to do with this is open a stable TCP connection with the server and receive and send data. If sending data from Data Mode is easy enough, I would like hear that solution first, but solutions to get the connection in Command Mode are equally appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up the PDP context? Obtained an IP address from the service provider? Post your sequence of commands so far.

Comment: I have experience only with SIM800f, but for that you can find some tutorials from the internet. For exampe [this](https://vsblogs.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/tcp-connection-over-gprs-using-sim900-and-at-commands/)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the issue that I was having is that I was not using the commands *AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","CMNET"* and *AT+CSOCKSETPN=1* before opening the TCP socket.

If you are trying to get the SIM5320 to open a transparent TCP connection, the commands you need to send are:

`AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","CMNET"
AT+CSOCKSETPN=1
AT+CIPMODE=1
AT+NETOPEN
AT+CIPOPEN=0,"TCP","TargetIpOrDomain",TargetPort`

When you are ready to end the session, you send `+++` to the chip to enter command mode. To close the connection you use `AT+CIPCLOSE=0` and `AT+NETCLOSE` to turn off the network connection mode.

Comment: Please see my question here on testing your connection, thanks!  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266974/testing-a-connection-to-a-tcp-socket-through-sim5320a-cellular-module